# jQuery JSON object not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

When sending JSON in a getJSON function in jQuery My response is erroring with:

Object is undefined:

```
  (?)(data=[[Object { @uid="0", @name="Well0"}, 
  Object { @uid="1", @name="Well1"}, Object { @uid="2", @name="Well2"}]])
```

In jQuery I have the following:

```
 $.getJSON("HandleGet",{Method:method},
         //Called on response from server
          function(data) {        
                // For every result returned from the JSON get
                  $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                      $("#dynamicCheck").append(item + " ");
```

Have checked all the jQuery documentation but cant seem to work it out.

Thanks

Comment: What does `.items` stand for? The JSON (which has a flawed format as you posted it...) doesn't contain `items` anywhere.

Comment: Can you use firebug to see what actual data is coming back from the server? I'm suspecting it's not well-formed JSON.

Comment: Yeah the JSON is output from using Maven JSON lib. Converted from XML, it seems to cut off the headers and some tags from the JSON.

Not sure what .items stands for. I was going by the jQuery documentation [link] (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Not sure what I can do now tbh...

Comment: Stripling - My response is showing:
data = [[Object { @uid="0", @name="Well0"}, Object { @uid="1", @name="Well1"}, Object { @uid="2", @name="Well2"}]]

I am using the Maven JSON lib to convert to JSON from XML. Is that badly formed? for some reason it strips the <wellList> tag away from the JSON and doesnt name each as well. Any ideas?

Comment: data.items will only exist if your Maven JSON lib converts your xml to a json having a root called items. If your json has a different root, you must use that. You can do a console.log(data) to print the object to the console and inspect what it contains.

Comment: object is undefined
each(object=undefined, callback=function(), args=undefined)jquery-1.6.4.js (line 632)
(?)(data=[[Object { @uid="0", @name="Well0"}, Object { @uid="1", @name="Well1"}, Object { @uid="2", @name="Well2"}]])

Comment: Thats the response I get from the console log

Comment: may be your success method is returning null or its not returning well formed json string.

Comment: Please provide the JSON string that the JSON lib produces.

Comment: [[
    {
    "@uid": "0",
    "@name": "Well0"
  },
    {
    "@uid": "1",
    "@name": "Well1"
  },
    {
    "@uid": "2",
    "@name": "Well2"
  }
]]